# PCA first or normalization first?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, classification, regression, pca

When doing regression or classification, what is the correct (or better) way to preprocess the data?

1. Normalize the data -> PCA -> training
2. PCA -> normalize PCA output -> training
3. Normalize the data -> PCA -> normalize PCA output -> training

Which of the above is more correct, or is the "standardized" way to preprocess the data? By "normalize" I mean either standardization, linear scaling or some other techniques.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should normalize the data before doing PCA. For example, consider the following situation. I create a data set `X` with a known correlation matrix `C`:

```
>> C = [1 0.5; 0.5 1];
>> A = chol(rho);
>> X = randn(100,2) * A;
```

If I now perform PCA, I correctly find that the principal components (the rows of the weights vector) are oriented at an angle to the coordinate axes:

```
>> wts=pca(X)
wts =
    0.6659    0.7461
   -0.7461    0.6659
```

If I now scale the first feature of the data set by 100, intuitively we think that the principal components shouldn't change:

```
>> Y = X;
>> Y(:,1) = 100 * Y(:,1);
```

However, we now find that the principal components are aligned with the coordinate axes:

```
>> wts=pca(Y)
wts =
    1.0000    0.0056
   -0.0056    1.0000
```

To resolve this, there are two options. First, I could rescale the data:

```
>> Ynorm = bsxfun(@rdivide,Y,std(Y))
```

(The weird `bsxfun` notation is used to do vector-matrix arithmetic in Matlab - all I'm doing is subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation of each feature).

We now get sensible results from PCA:

```
>> wts = pca(Ynorm)
wts =
   -0.7125   -0.7016
    0.7016   -0.7125
```

They're slightly different to the PCA on the original data because we've now guaranteed that our features have unit standard deviation, which wasn't the case originally.

The other option is to perform PCA using the correlation matrix of the data, instead of the outer product:

```
>> wts = pca(Y,'corr')
wts =
    0.7071    0.7071
   -0.7071    0.7071
```

In fact this is completely equivalent to standardizing the data by subtracting the mean and then dividing by the standard deviation. It's just more convenient. In my opinion you should *always* do this unless you have a good reason not to (e.g. if you *want* to pick up differences in the variation of each feature).

Comment: "You should normalize the data before doing PCA". Is it normalize or, rather, standardize or any of the two? If not standardize, why not? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You need to normalize the data first **always**. Otherwise, PCA or other techniques that are used to reduce dimensions will give different results.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize the data at first. Actually some R packages, useful to perform PCA analysis, normalize data automatically before performing PCA. 
If the variables have different units or describe different characteristics, it is mandatory to normalize.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is the 3rd option as after doing pca we have to normalize the pca output as the whole data will have completely different standard. we have to normalize the dataset before and after PCA as it will more accuarate.

Answer (score -1):

I got another reason in PCA objective function.
May you see detail in this link
[enter link description here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32174/pca-objective-function-what-is-the-connection-between-maximizing-variance-and-m/136072#136072)
Assuming the X matrix has been normalized before PCA.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better. Also, provide a basic coverage of the content of your link, in case it stops working in the future.