# Doing PCA in Weka

Tags: weka, covariance, correlation, pca

I am trying to do PCA for dimension reduction in WEKA (Classification Problem).

I have 200 attributes in my data and close to 2100 rows.

Here are the steps that i follow

- Import csv file in WEKA explorer
- In preprocess tab, apply, Normalize data (To bring entire data in range of [0,1]
- Then implement PCA.

  - In options for PCA, there is an option for centerData which if set to False, would calculate using correlation matrix after standardizing data (Correct me if i am wrong) and if set to true would using covariance matrix.

My doubt is

1. Should i be normalizing data before implementing PCA or not? I tried doing it before and after normalizing i am getting different results. So i am confused.
2. Should i Standardize data (bring mean to 0) and then apply PCA.

What is the option that i should select in PCA WEKA  for centerData option in either case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question has been answered in part here: [PCA first or normalization first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119913/pca-first-or-normalization-first)

To answer your questions directly:

Normalizing would be a personal choice.  If you set centerData=TRUE, and do not normalize or standardize your data, some attributes with large values will have greater influence in the PCA.  If you set centerData=FALSE, Weka standardizes the data for you.

And just to confirm your suspicions, in Weka, centerData does the following:

**centerData=TRUE**

- Centers your data (does not normalize or standardize, so if you decide to do that, you need to do  it before)
- PCA is performed with the **covariance matrix**

**centerData=FALSE**

- PCA is performed with the **correlation matrix** (data is standardized by the method)

Comment: Thanks @Walter I am still trying to figure out which one would suit best for my dataset, as i could see deviation of few percent (2-3 %) in accuracy when trying above options. 
P.S - Out of 200 attributes, around 180-185 attributes are already in [0-1] range. Problem is because of other remaining attributes.

Comment: That is understandable.  You have to do what makes the most sense for your data!  However, keep in mind that the 2-3% deviation in accuracy could simply be an artifact of your testing method (possible overfitting).