# how to plot the data for linear model with 3 variables in matlab?

Tags: matlab, regression, linear-regression

To plot the data in 3D plane for this model: y = a + a1*x1 + a2*x2
I do like this, the figure is shown in this website (http://kr.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html) , x1, x2, and y denote respectively vectors X, Y, and Z.

```
scatter3(x1,x2,y,'filled')
hold on
x1fit = min(x1):100:max(x1);
x2fit = min(x2):10:max(x2);
[X1FIT,X2FIT] = meshgrid(x1fit,x2fit);
YFIT = b(1) + b(2)*X1FIT + b(3)*X2FIT + b(4)*X1FIT.*X2FIT;
mesh(X1FIT,X2FIT,YFIT)
xlabel('Weight')
ylabel('Horsepower')
zlabel('MPG')
view(50,10)
```

My question is how can I plot the model with 3 variables in 3D: y = a + a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a3*x3 ? 
I used the below code to get the linear model

```
X2 = [ImageSize Resolution PSNR];
lm3 = regress(K_Number, X2);
```

a1,a2,a3 <-> X2 vector.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data so that we can produce a plot and show you? It would also be good if you could publish an image of what you are after.

Comment: @kkuilla I've edited my question, could you help me check again!!!

Comment: The only way you can do this is if you assign a colour value to each 3D point.  This is essentially a 4D function - `(x1,x2,x3) -> y` which obviously can't be physically visualized unless you cheat, such as drawing a 3D grid and assigning a colour to each 3D point.  If this is what you want, then I can write an answer.

Comment: @rayryeng Example in this tutorial is exactly what I want to do. MPG is response, X = [Weight,Horsepower,Acceleration] is predictor vector. How can they represent that data in plane? How can I plot the linear model y ~ 1 + x1 + x2 + x3 with coefficient like this??? If impossible, could you help me write an answer!!!

Comment: @rayryeng, sorry I missed http://kr.mathworks.com/help/stats/understanding-linear-regression-outputs.html

Comment: Thank you @rayryeng Does any other way to represent the correlate between of variables? So, I'm confusing in the academic, how can they Interpret Linear Regression with multiple variables ? Could you give me a suggestion about the solution for this ?

Comment: It's not possible to create a plane with three independent variables. It can't be visually created unless you cheat as I said.   You'd basically have to define a 3D grid like what is given by `meshgrid/ndgrid`, you put each unique triple of values into the regression formula and see what the output is.  This output would give you a colour on a colour map.  This would be a 3D cube of points where each point is coloured according to a colour map.  The colour gives you an indication of what the output predicted value was.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank a lot Now I'm clear, Could you give a sample code to draw it on 3D grid and assigning a colour y to each 3D point !!!

Comment: @rayryeng this is my data, 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BySwNFtG9p7cM3Bqb2hlSU5fenc/view?usp=sharing
column number 4 is responsor, and column 1,2,3 are predictor

Comment: @rayryeng Could you please help me check it!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function to solve the equation (functionSolver) based on three inputs (y,x1,x2)
Define a grid of the region you care about

```
y = -100:1:100;
x1 = -50:0.05:25;
x2 = 10:0.5:100;
(outx, outy, outz) = functionSolver(x1,x2,y); However you defined this
plot3(outx, outy, outz); This will plot the output as defined in your grid.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but my question related with linear model for 3 variables, I mean to plot the data, I need to input at least 4 parameters (y, x1, x2, x3, x4)???