# How to reduce matrix dimension using PCA in matlab?

Tags: matlab, pca

I wanted to reduce a bigger dimension matrix i.e. 2000*768; to some lower dimensions i.e 200*768 or 400*400 (not fixed); using principal component analysis (PCA) in MatLab. I wanted to do it for feature dimension reduction. How can I do it easily? And please suggest me some tutorials to understand PCA better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour. Usually you show what have you tried before asking a question here.

Comment: Surprised you didn't use Google.  The duplicate link was the first one I found.

Answer (score 1):

PCA is a really useful tool for dimensionality reduction, but it should be used when you understand exactly what it is doing and what you are getting out of it. For a good intro [click here](https://georgemdallas.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/principal-component-analysis-4-dummies-eigenvectors-eigenvalues-and-dimension-reduction/) - it is a decent explanation which is not too hard to follow. There is also [this article](http://www.matlabtips.com/pca-demystified/) which is a quick DIY walkthrough which may help you understand better what is going on.

Once you know what you are getting, [PCA is easy in matlab](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html). Just type `pca(X)` and you can perform it on data set `X`.

What you get out is very much dependent on what you get in (e.g. [things like normalisation are very important for input data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119913/pca-first-or-normalization-first)), and you can use extra parameters that are worth knowing about to set up you principal component analysis. [See matlab's guide here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/feature-transformation.html#f75476).

What you are looking for in dimensionality reduction to best represent the data with as few components as possible. Using the `explained` output of `[coeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained] = pca(X)` you get a vector telling you how much of the data is explained by each principal component, which gives you a good indication of whether dimensionality reduction can be done.

Comment: While the answer is interesting, I don't think you should be answering this type of question, as it encourages off-topic discussions.

Comment: Ok, left it as generic as possible so that it can be investigated if OP wanted. Probably should have just commented it.

Comment: Actually questions asking for resources are considered offtopic by SO's standards